# Postgres: how to insert and delete many records and to not run out of space

Tags: postgresql, vacuum, autovacuum

I have a PostgreSQL installation deployed in Kubernetes (with the CloudNative operator) and allocated a 25GB volume for it. My architecture involves several microservices interacting with various databases. Here's the setup:

1. A custom-made load testing tool, which sends 100-1000 requests per second via REST.
2. Service A, which is database-less, receives requests through REST and forwards them to Service B via AMQP.
3. Service B, which receives data from Service A via AMQP and stores it in the database.
4. A background thread pool in Service B retrieves data portions from the database, processes them, and then sends them to Services C and D via AMQP.
5. Services C and D, which receive data from Service B via AMQP and store it in their respective databases.
6. A custom database cleaning tool, which, once a minute, deletes the oldest records from all databases so that each table has no more than N records (where N ranges from 100k to 1M). Additionally, it performs a vacuum (but not a full vacuum) once every 10 minutes.

With this configuration, I encounter a problem in less than an hour - the database size nearly reaches 25GB, and everything comes to a halt. I had assumed that running vacuum would mark the deleted records for reuse, but it appears that only a VACUUM FULL effectively frees up space. Naturally, I would prefer to use VACUUM FULL sparingly because it locks the databases. However, I am already performing a simple VACUUM – why isn't that sufficient? Auto-vacuum is also enabled with default settings. The code in all applications works correctly; there are no forgotten connections or similar issues. With VACUUM FULL, the system operates for hours under a ~500rps load and remains relatively stable. "Relatively" because VACUUM FULL causes significant disruptions, of course. But thanks to AMQP, no data is lost.

There are no foreign keys and no complex queries in my system, which is designed for high loads, so I aim to keep it as simple as possible. The role of Service B is merely to perform basic data processing (JSON transformation) and insert or update a record in the "datagrams" table, then insert a record in the "journal" table within the same transaction at the ReadCommitted isolation level.
What's wrong with the "simple vacuum" (that takes tens of seconds sometimes as well but at least does not block everything)? In fact with my cleaning utility working each db must be no more 1-2Gb, so if vacuum mark records for reuse, databases should not grow after 2-3Gb (taking into account that indexes are not processed by simple vacuum). But they do grow.

Here is the schema of database for service B as an example (D and C have similar, even simpler):

```
CREATE TABLE public.datagrams (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    incoming_id text NOT NULL,
    sender text NOT NULL,
    body text NOT NULL,
    errors text NULL,
    status public.datagram_status NOT NULL,
    document_type text DEFAULT ''::text NOT NULL,
    target_document_type text DEFAULT ''::text NOT NULL,
    created timestamptz NOT NULL,
    modified timestamptz NULL,
    processing_instance text NULL,
    processing_started_at timestamptz NULL,
    retries int4 DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT datagrams_incoming_id_key UNIQUE (incoming_id),
    CONSTRAINT datagrams_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE INDEX datagrams_created_idx ON public.datagrams USING btree (created);
CREATE INDEX datagrams_modified_idx ON public.datagrams USING btree (modified);
CREATE INDEX datagrams_processing_instance_idx ON public.datagrams USING btree (processing_instance);
CREATE INDEX datagrams_processing_started_at_idx ON public.datagrams USING btree (processing_started_at);
CREATE INDEX datagrams_status_ind ON public.datagrams USING btree (status);

CREATE TABLE public.journal (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    incoming_id text NOT NULL,
    status public.datagram_status NOT NULL,
    errors text NULL,
    auditor text NULL,
    stamp timestamptz NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT datagram_errors_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE INDEX journal_stamp_idx ON public.journal USING btree (stamp);
CREATE INDEX journal_status_ind ON public.journal USING btree (status);
```

Comment: Do you have any long running transactions that might still see old records?

Comment: @bobflux no long transactions at all, moreover every db query have a timeout context 40 seconds. background part of service C selects portions with select ... limit ... order by, but does it pretty quick

Comment: Does this help? https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/reasons-why-vacuum-wont-remove-dead-rows/ also can you post VACUUM VERBOSE?

Comment: @bobflux thanks, will check and get back soon

Comment: So, where is the space going?  Which table or index is it in (if any)?  Or is spread evenly throughout all of them?

Comment: Where is AMQP storing its stuff?

Answer (score 0):

Autovacuum is probably too slow to keep up with the workload. Set `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay` to 0.

The better approach is to use partitioning to get rid of old data efficiently.